# Traefik and odoo version 16

Tags: websocket, traefik, odoo-16

Hello guys I have a problem with traefik and odoo 16
this is my compose odoo 16 compose and some traefik lables testing and I receive this errors:

version: "3.9"
services:
odoo:
image: traefik:v2.10
environment:
- HOST=postgresql_local
- USER=local_test
- PASSWORD=12345678
networks:
- swarm-scope
volumes:
- odoo16_data:/var/lib/odoo
- odoo16_conf:/etc/odoo/
- odoo16_addons:/mnt/extra-addons
deploy:
labels:
- "traefik.enable=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo.rule=Host(`odoo.test.local`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo.service=odoo16@docker"
- "traefik.http.services.odoo.loadbalancer.server.port=8069"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo.entrypoints=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo.tls=true"
- "traefik.docker.network=swarm-scope"
# ##
##
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo-websock.rule=Host(`odoo.test.local`) && \ (PathPrefix(`/websocket`))"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo-websock.entrypoints=https"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo-websock.service=odoo-websock"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo-websock.tls=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.odoo-websock.middlewares=odoo-headers"
- "traefik.http.services.odoo-websock.loadbalancer.server.port=8072"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.odoo-headers.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=GET"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.odoo-headers.headers.accesscontrolallowheaders=*"
##
#
I receive this error
[2023-06-16 12:32:51] "GET /websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 318 0.062449
If someone know about this issue thank you